# How to get notified on pod restart?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have applications running fine on GKE. Recently, there was a 3rd party API causing the server to crash. Luckily, I set up livenessProbe earlier and the pod managed to restart, and everyone was happy.

I would like to get notified when the pod is started. Do you know how to get notified?

Answer (score 0):

There are lifecycle hooks that could work for your case: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/

You could set a pre-start hook that, for instance, sends a post request to an API endpoint, or you could configure mail so you receive the notification in your mail.

Comment: What kind of API endpoint can it be? A google service or AWS?

Comment: I haven't looked much into it, but maybe something like this could work: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/Welcome.html or https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/